# My Codewars Script Fails The Test ..? (Largest 5 digit number in a series)

Tags: javascript

JavaScript beginner here. I was attempting a codewars (challenge) kata. It keeps telling me that my solution isn't working and I want to know why. How do I fix my code to work? Here are the contents of the question.

```
"Complete the solution so that it returns the greatest 
sequence of five consecutive digits found within the number given."

"1234567890" - 67890 is the greatest sequence of 5 consecutive digits.
```

Link to kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/51675d17e0c1bed195000001/train/javascript

My Code:

```js
function solution(digits){
  digits = +digits.split('');
  let solution = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    let pending = digits[i] + digits[i+1] + digits[i+2] + digits[i+3] + digits[i+4];
    if (pending > solution) {
      solution = pending;
    }
  }
  return solution;
}
```

Best / Most explained answers will get the green check mark.
It also wouldn't hurt to let me know if my solution is a bit redundant
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood "greatest". You don't have to add the digits, but really to take all the 5 consecutive digits as a number.
You could have written:

```
let pending = digits[i]*10000 + digits[i+1]*1000 + digits[i+2]*100 + digits[i+3]*10 + digits[i+4];
```

Indeed, you if you don't multiply, 12345 will give you 1+2+3+4+5 = 15, but you have to get 12345, not 15.

Also, you have to stop your loop 5 digits before the end:

```
for (let i = 0; i < digits.length-4; i++) {
```

Another error is your conversion to anarray of numbers:

```
digits = digits.split('').map(x=>+x);
```

**This is what your solution would look like:**

```
function solution(digits){
  digits = digits.split('').map(x=>+x);
  let solution = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < digits.length -4 ; i++) {
    let pending = digits[i]*10000 + digits[i+1]*1000 + digits[i+2]*100 + digits[i+3]*10 + digits[i+4];
    if (pending > solution) {
      solution = pending;
    }
  }
  return solution;
}
```

**This is what I would have done:**

```
function solution(digits){
  return Math.max(...digits.split('').map((x,i,a)=>+(a.slice(i, i+5).join(''))))
}
```

You take the "digits" and you create an array of all the digits separated:

```
digits.split('')
```

With this array, for each index (i), you put in another array the sequence of the 5 consecutive digits:

```
.map((x,i,a)=>a.slice(i, i+5)
```

You join these digits:

```
.join()
```

You transform it into a number:

```
+
```

You take the max:

```
Math.max(...)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Why multiply all the things by the 100s?

Comment: Another thing is that your solution is hard to read because it is clogged on a single line

Comment: I edited to explain the multiplications. For the "hard" thing, you'd better get used to it, it's not this complicated. I'll edit to explain more.

Comment: It wasn't "hard" per say, it just isn't as clean as it could be because everything was forced onto one line rather than being spreaded out. Getting the shortest solution possible isn't always the way to go because of other factors such as performance. Also, sorry about the multiplying things by 100s thing, that was written before I finished reading the post. I know that those are for the 'places' in scientific notation. For example, 6 * 100 is 600,etc. Other than that, good answer :D

Comment: I guess next time I should try to understand the problem being asked

Comment: I'd have done `Math.max(...digits.split('').map((_, i) => +(digits.substring(i, i+5))));`. You reckon `slice + join` is faster than `substring`?

Comment: Actually the fastest solution is the corrected version of the author's script. The one liners are just here for the beauty of code :)

Comment: For readability and maintenance I recommend the solution "This is what your solution would look like", the others are terribly poor in terms of performance. I wouldn't use them in my projects.